# Windows phone header same for all pages

Tags: windows-phone-7, layout, header, frame

Im creating an App and I have a header that its the same for all pages (a footer as well, but that one ill create using the app bar).

My question is, what's the best way to do this if I dont want to repeat the header (code it) in every page.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best was to do this is create the following:

1. UserControl for the Header
2. UserControl for the Footer
3. Everything Page or UserControl should show these items.

Comment: If I use an animation to transition between pages, will those controls also be in the animation?

Comment: If each page contains the same footer and Header then yes. 
If you have 1 page with a frame and 2 UserControls then no.

Answer (score 0):

Look at templating your project so that you can have multiple views and and multiple regions

I would also look at Prism: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you use as header and footer, if it is a simple text then you could use the default page templates and Bind the text to a static resource defined in the App.Xaml, if it is more complex then you could create a user control as suggested. You could create animations too and play this when your page is displayed.

Static resource in App.Xaml as an `Application.Resource` :

```
<Application.Resources>
     <sys:String x:Key="applicationTitle">Your Title!</sys:String>
</Application.Resources>
```

You need to add this namespace to the App.Xaml too :

```
 xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

Or you could use MVVM too to create a View and a ViewModel for the header. If you are new to MVVM then take a look at Galasofts MVVM light.

[GalaSoft MVVM](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/)