# Windows phone page styling

Tags: windows-phone-7, styling

I have a few pages and want that they use one style. See in images, for example. as you can see all three pages have static styled header. So how i can do it?

Sorry if the question is easy, it's in the evening and i can't think very clear, and been working really hard...

I tried setting Template, but i keep getting an exception, that i cannot use templating for UserControl...

[image]

Why can't using like following?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Style>
        <Style TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationPage">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:PhoneApplicationFrame">
                        <StackPanel Background="Black">
                            <Border Height="100" Width="100" Background="Red"/>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a UserControl that includes a StackPanel, with a horizontal orientation, then add two controls inside the StackPanel, maybe an Image and a TextBlock, add margins as required, add colours as required. Once your UserControl is defined, add this UserControl to all the pages what you want to have the same look and feel. You might even be able to move this UserControl to a base page and derive your pages from this base page.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. My question like similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930580/windows-phone-header-same-for-all-pages

Oh...